# What does "Q" (Quantum) stand for in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm one of the QGIS users.

Why did Gary Sherman use *'Quantum'* for this software name?

Answer (score 13):

From the [note in the changelog](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog200/index.html#feature-quantum-gis-is-now-known-only-as-qgis):

> "The ‘Quantum’ in ‘Quantum GIS’ never had any particular significance"

My *guess* is that the word Quantum was picked because it starts with Q to match the underlying [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) framework, but I have no evidence for that.

Comment: I see! Thank you for your quck reply!

Comment: I'd always assumed it was connected to its use of the Qt toolkit. Lots of software that uses Qt starts with a Q.

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, I assume that too. My guess based on the changelog is that Quantum was picked because it starts with Q, but I have no evidence for that.